# Assigning a value to a certain, varying column conditional on a value in a different column in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have had trouble finding a good solution to this problem. Many other similar questions on StackExchange have yielded me an inefficient solution as of yet, but I feel like there must be far more efficient way.

Suppose I have a dataframe in R as such:

```
ID cat cost   1  2  3  4  5
1    1   24  NA NA NA NA NA
1    2   12  NA NA NA NA NA
1    5  104  NA NA NA NA NA
2    1   21  NA NA NA NA NA
2    4   13  NA NA NA NA NA
```

My actual data has 25 columns rather than 1 through 5, and has millions of rows. These numbered columns correspond to all the values that 'cat' takes on, one through five in this example but one through twenty five in my own data. My goal is to get it to look like this, putting the value within cost into the category column for each row.

```
ID cat cost   1  2  3  4  5
1    1   24  24 NA NA NA NA
1    2   12  NA 12 NA NA NA
1    5  104  NA NA NA NA 104
2    1   21  NA 21 NA NA NA
2    4   13  NA NA NA 13 NA
```

And so on and so forth. Essentially, I want it to go through every row, look at what value exists in "cat", then place the value of cost in the column that has the same value as the value in that row's cat. After I do this, I'm going to condense the dataset by crunching the rows together, so that you're left only with one row per ID, such that these rows have the value for each category filled out. Each row would look like this, where x,y,z,w,v are just standins for generic cost numbers.

```
ID cat cost  1  2  3  4  5
1  NA   NA   x  y  z  w  v
2  NA   NA  x2 y2 z2 w2 v2
```

However, I know how to do this once I get the data as I indicated in the second code block (but so you are aware what my goals are, I have stated it). The problem is that my solution to the initial problem of adding the cost to each corresponding category column is very slow and inefficient and would take hours to run. The code I have used is below.

```
x <- colnames(CollapsedMTBI)
###CollapsedMTBI is the name of my dataframe

for(i in 1:length(CollapsedMTBI$cost)){
  a <- as.numeric(CollapsedMTBI$cat[i] + 5)
  CollapsedMTBI[[x[a]]][i] <- CollapsedMTBI$cost[i]
  }
  print(100*(i/length(CollapsedMTBI$cost)))
}
### As a sanity check I had it print out where I was at in the process. It goes very slowly.
### The +5 when defining a is used because I have five columns before the category columns begin;
### In my example above I only had three, but in my own data I have five.
```

I haven't been able to find anyone else performing this type of maneuver online despite many searches. I figure there must be a function that could perform this for me, maybe something in dplyr or tidyr or something. I also know you could use a bunch of conditional statements, but since I have 25 columns to check it feels like that would be even less efficient than what I have now. Anyone have a more efficient way to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), cat = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 4L), cost = c(24L, 12L, 104L, 21L, 13L), `1` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `5` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Code:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(1,2,3)) %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(as.integer(name)==cat,cost,value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
     ID   cat  cost   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1    24    24    NA    NA    NA    NA
2     1     2    12    NA    12    NA    NA    NA
3     1     5   104    NA    NA    NA    NA   104
4     2     1    21    21    NA    NA    NA    NA
5     2     4    13    NA    NA    NA    13    NA
```

Comment: It appears this would have worked, but my desktop doesn't have the RAM to process it since I'm getting the "cannot allocate vector of 3.2Gb" error, which is surprising given that I have 32GB. Any way that I could break this up into sections bit by bit? e.g. only do categories 1,2,3 first, then 4,5,6, and so on?

Comment: @TyroneShoelaces Are you working on `R` with 64 bits? That is strange, having a lot of ram. For sure that should work if you split by sections. Let me know if that works!

Comment: For reference, my data frame has over 17 million rows and has 30 columns in total. I'm certain I have the 64 bit version. That said, I was able to modify the rows in the pivot_longer() function so that it only did three rows at a time and simply added steps in the function so that it took 8 steps but did work. Even with the size of my data, it only took about 8-10 minutes to run with my i5 6500 CPU. Will accept this as correct! Thanks!

Comment: @TyroneShoelaces Thanks to you dear!